# TableView cell, where to style selected cell?

Tags: swift, select, tableview, cell

I was looking around in this forum but haven't found anything related this.

I would like to take control of UITableView's selection function: style the cell on select & deselect, and make it remain after being reused.

---

The action when the user click is coming with animation, it is decleared in the `TableViewController`'s file of course:

```
func selectWorldMessage(indexPath: IndexPath) {

       ...

            cell.attributedText = worldMessage.message.wholeWorldMessageAttributedString()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                cell.bubbleImageView.tintColor = appColors.worldMessageBubbleSelected
                cell.timeLabel.isHidden = false
                cell.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 14
                cell.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 14
                cell.timeLabel.alpha = 1.0

                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
                self.lastContentOffsetY = nil
            }, completion: nil)

       ...

func deselectWorldMessage(indexPath: IndexPath) {

       ...
```

**But.. let's assume you scroll down and up, the cell gets reused. I have to style it again. Where should I do it?**

**A)** In the `TableViewController`'s `cellForRowAt` function?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

....

            // If previously was selected
            if (currentSelectedIndexPath == indexPath) {

                cell.messageLabel.attributedText = worldMessage.message.wholeWorldMessageAttributedString()
                cell.bubbleImageView.tintColor = appColors.worldMessageBubbleSelected
                cell.timeLabel.isHidden = false
                cell.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 14
                cell.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 14

            } else {

                cell.messageLabel.attributedText = worldMessage.message.shortenWorldMessageIfNeededAttributedString()
                cell.bubbleImageView.tintColor = appColors.worldMessageBubble
                cell.timeLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 10
                cell.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 10


            }
```

**B)** Or in the `Cell`'s `setSelected` function?

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if selected == true {
            self.messageLabel.attributedText = worldMessage.message.wholeWorldMessageAttributedString()
            self.bubbleImageView.tintColor = appColors.worldMessageBubbleSelected
            self.timeLabel.isHidden = false
            self.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 14
            self.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 14
        } else {
            self.messageLabel.attributedText = worldMessage.message.shortenWorldMessageIfNeededAttributedString()
            self.bubbleImageView.tintColor = appColors.worldMessageBubble
            self.timeLabel.isHidden = true
            self.messageLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 10
            self.messageLabelTopConstraint.constant = 10
        }

    }
```

What would be better & less energy consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be inside your cell file because It is cell related things and It will remain after being reused.  It's to your view controller to handle the "filling" logic for your cells but in this case you want to change UI style of the cells. If you put the code in view controller, when you change the cell (by adding or removing a label), you have to change your controller too. Also you will need to save selected index path to check in cellForRowAt method.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if selected {
            self.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I’m using those aswell, thank you the question is, if I decleare a custom style when the cell is selected (changing a few colors, showing the time) where should I put that code? (So that after being reused it remains). In the cell’s file, or in the viewController’s file?